# Why am I getting invalid syntax when adding second plot to plt.plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Hi am getting invalid syntax on line 6

```
x = []
y = []
x2 = []
y2 = []
plt.plot(x,y,label=(+str(incur1)+ '/' +str(incur2))
plt.plot(x2,y2,label=(+str(incur2)+ '/' +str(incur1))
plt.xlabel ('Time')
plt.ylabel ('Ex Rate')
plt.title (+incur1+ '/' +incur2+ '/nEx Rate Data')
plt.legend()
```

Will later add data and datetime as so

```
time = t.datetime
x.append(time)
y.append(first_exRtRate1)
```

tried making strings

```
label1 = (incur1+ '/' +incur2)
label2 = (incur2+ '/' +incur1)
```

then

```
plt.plot(x,y,label=(+str(label1))
```

still error
was told missing a )
tried

```
plt.plot(x,y,label=(+str(incur1)+ '/' +str(incur2)))
```

still error

Comment: You are missing a `)`

Comment: what at the end? added one ) at end now error has moved one line down

Comment: It is better to edit the post, than to put that information in a comment.

Comment: sorry always forget\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved with

```
label1 = (incur1+ '/' +incur2)
```

and

```
plt.plot(x, y, label = label1)
```